# Fastest way to bootstrap (or generate scaffolding code) for a twitter compatible api

Tags: php, rest, code-generation, twitter

I need to generate a twitter compatible rest api for an web application.

I'm looking for a way to quickly generate all the api stubs

I'm just making a POC here so I don't need anything fancy, just something to help me see if
and shooting in the rigth direction.

**EDIT:**

In response to Darrel Miller:

Yes I only need a twitter compatible API. I don't know if the twitter API is RESTful or not,
because everyone seems to have a different definition a what RESTful means.

I guess I have to make another question about the truly meaning of a RESTful API, but for now, I just need a Twitter Compatible API, so that I can change the endpoint url in
applications like TwetDeck.

Comment: What do you mean by Twitter-compatible? Do you want to be able to replace the Twitter URL in source code and have it work with your webapp?

Comment: If you code-gen API stubs I can guarantee that you will not be "shooting in the right direction" to build a RESTful system.

Comment: @Simon Brown: Yes, that is exactly what I want, not only for webapps, also for twitter clients like Tweetdeck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of automating this process, but the Apigee.com site is the best working example of all the Twitter API calls. It will show you what you are writing against. Be aware that the official docs on Dev.twitter.com are wrong and out of date in many, many ways. At least the Apigee copy of the API calls work.

http://app.apigee.com/console/twitter